# Use window.print content to download a web page as pdf

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, moodle

I would like to have a link that when is clicked, automatically starts the download of the printable version of the web page.

I'm using Moodle. The content I want it's exactly the same  If I download the page using ctrl + p and saving as pdf or using

```
<a href=\"whatever.htm\" onClick=\"window.print();return false\">Download web page</a>
```

I want exactly that content because using this way, the header, sidebar and footer is removed. I don't want css.

I'm not using this because this doesn't work in some browsers.

I'd rather not using pdf libraries like tcpdf because Moodle loads the content in a dynamic way and send this to a libraries like that is a mess.

I tried using sites like pdfcrowd.com but this kind of sites don't work when the site you want to convert to pdf uses  a server-side session to identify the user.

Comment: Users can (depending on the browser and OS) print to PDF of their own choosing. Or you can create a PDF using server-side coding tools and make it downloadable. But you cannot specify "print to PDF".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe that there is a way to do this with `window.print()`. However, there are HTML to PDF converters available for free, and you could automatically start a download with that. An example of this would be [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF), a free library for converting HTML to a PDF with Javascript

Comment: Thank, I used TCPDF to print it in pdf and everything works almost well

Comment: @Toquis Can you please explain What exactly you did to make it work?

Answer (score 5):

**There is easy ways to use jsPDF its very simple just you will use JSpdf Library **

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script>

function onClick() {
  var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
  pdf.canvas.height = 72 * 11;
  pdf.canvas.width = 72 * 8.5;

  pdf.fromHTML(document.body);

  pdf.save('test.pdf');
};

var element = document.getElementById("clickbind");
element.addEventListener("click", onClick);
```

Comment: fromHTML will not load css for you, so its not identical, you need to use addHTML and html2canvas.js