# create a chrome extension that will click & print those webpages automatically into PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, printing, google-chrome-extension, pdf-generation

I have looked through the forum but couldn't find an answer to printing websites as PDFs.

### Problem:

I have to log onto a secure webpage (that require login) and then print multiple webpages as PDF.
For example,

1. Login to Gmail
2. Print the Inbox Tab as PDF using Ctrl P
3. Print the Sent Tab as PDF using Ctrl P
4. Print the Label Tab as PDF using Ctrl P

### My current process:

- Just login and click into each link and print the webpage into PDF one by one

### The idea:

Currently, I am trying to create a chrome extension that will click & print those webpages automatically into PDF.

(Since I am already logging in manually - there is no need to code the login part. Just to code the print as PDF, using adobe pdf as printer, and clicking to that webpage automatically)

Please let me know how you would approach it. Or if there is an existing script I can learn from.

Resources I have found so far:

- http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3471121
- [automate print website to pdf while changing input value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25897618/automate-print-website-to-pdf-while-changing-input-value)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646168/use-window-print-content-to-download-a-web-page-as-pdf This could be of use.